# Missing context replaced by question marks!

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

On Windows phone it's working fine, but in the iPad version isn't. All the texts in the boxes have being replaced by question marks (**???**)

**System**

- iPad 4
- iOS 7
- Update: 1.3.2700

Comment: What's the update?

Comment: Version 1.3.2700 according to the in-game settings screen

Comment: If you can add a screen shot will improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced (and fixed) this same problem in the past.

Since they began rolling out content without full updates, there have been numerous errors of this type.  And, they are all cured the same way.

Exit the game entirely, and reopen it.  It should work for you as it did for me.

If not, reinstall the game.

Comment: I force close all apps every night, and it still get this error. If it wasn't for my phone I would not have had any idea what the new features are for. Sadly I missed out on the imperial marches level because of this error

Comment: @user69547 Sorry, I cannot help then.  Try reinstalling.  Just make certain you save an online version first.  Force closing worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I will edit to reflect this and you can accept.  Thanks.